# Mapping out state with react and materialui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to output data into its respective table columns using state. I have data in each state key (`rentalsData`, `driversData`, `vehiclesData`). Whats the best way to effectively map out each key state into a column?

```
export default class TableExampleControlled extends Component {
  state = {
    rentalsData: [],
    driversData: [],
    vehiclesData: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Promise.all([rentals(), drivers(), vehicles()])
    .then(result => {
      const [ rentalsData, driversData, vehiclesData ] = result;
      this.setState({ rentalsData,driversData, vehiclesData });  
    });
  };
  render() {     
    const tableRow = this.state.rentalsData.map((data) =>
      <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>
        <TableRowColumn key={data.status}>{data.status}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={data.vehicle}>{data.vehicle}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={data.driver}>{data.driver}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={data.email}>{data.email}</TableRowColumn>        
        <TableRowColumn key={data.start_date}>{data.start_date}
        </TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={data.end_date}>{data.end_date}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={data.rate}>{data.rate}</TableRowColumn>
      </TableBody>
    );

    return (
      <Table onRowSelection={this.handleRowSelection}>
        <TableHeader displaySelectAll={false} adjustForCheckbox={false}>
          <TableRow>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Vehicle</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Driver</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Email</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Start</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Return</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn>Rate</TableHeaderColumn>            
          </TableRow>
        </TableHeader>
        <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>
          {tableRow}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code exactly ? You seem to only be accessing data from `rentalsData`. What does the data inside your state looks like ? Are the 3 arrays the same length and do the rows in each array correspond exactly to each other ?

Comment: @klugjo well, the problem is I would like to access data from all 3 variables and map them to `TableRowColumn` but the data is ordered differently. The data inside each state vary and aren't the same length either. So in order to fill out `data.email` I'd need to grab it from driversData not rentalsData. Its all mixed up and Im not sure the best way to go about this

Comment: Then you need to figure out the logic on how to do that, but since you didn't explain anything about this in your description, there is no way I can help